# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: sql, oracle, python-2.7

Can anyone help me to find why I am getting an invalid number error from this code:

```
prcpId=cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)

cursor.execute("""insert into PC_REROUTING_CONF_PCBS (PRCP_SOURCE_FC_PCB_ID,PRCP_TARGET_FC_PCB_ID,PRCP_MIN_ORDER_LINES,PRCP_MAX_ORDER_LINES) values ('+ str(sourcePcbId) +','+ str(targetPcbId) +', 1, 999)returning prcp_id INTO :v_prcp_id""", v_prcp_id = prcpId)

v_prcp_id=prcpId.getvalue()

print v_prcp_id
```

Comment: What are `sourcePcbId` and `targetPcbId` set to? And why are you embedding those values in the statement rather than bind them?

Comment: Hi Alex, your comment solved my problem. :) i bind them and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You have problem with Your query string here... Try something like this, and see if it works:

```
sql_str = "insert into PC_REROUTING_CONF_PCBS (PRCP_SOURCE_FC_PCB_ID,PRCP_TARGET_FC_PCB_ID,PRCP_MIN_ORDER_LINES,PRCP_MAX_ORDER_LINES) values ('{0}','{1}', 1, 999) returning prcp_id INTO :v_prcp_id"
cursor.execute(sql_str.format(str(sourcePcbId),str(targetPcbId)), v_prcp_id = prcpId)
```

If it works, do **not** use it in production. :) Use binding mechanism. Always. Otherwise You are vunerable to [SQL injection](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: I used the binding mechanism and it worked. Anyways thanks for the answer.

Comment: I think `'{0}'` should just be `{0}`, without the quotes; otherwise you're doing implicit conversion from string to number, which works but is pointless. That has highlighted why the original statement is failing though. Completely agree binds should be used anyway though.

Comment: @Alex Poole I prefered not to guess type of sourcePcbId and targetPcbId, to eliminate probability of some other error here. If they are ints - I totally agree with You.

Comment: @Bidyut If my answer works and is helpfull in some way, please upvote it. I am grinding rep here! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of the quotes you've used to embed the ID variables:

```
values ('+ str(sourcePcbId) +','+ str(targetPcbId) +', 1, 999)
```

Your overall statement is enclosed in double quotes in the client application. You've used single quotes around the values, so you're passing string literals not your ID values; effectively the same as doing:

```
select to_number('+ str(sourcePcbId) +') from dual;
```

And that string literal clearly is not a number. The `sourcePcbId` and `targetPcbId` values in your client are never visible inside the SQL statement, you just have string literals that happen to look the same as those names.

If you were going to embed them then you'd need to close the client double-quotes:

```
values ("+ str(sourcePcbId) +","+ str(targetPcbId) +", 1, 999)
```

although I'm not sure why you have the set of three double quotes at the start and end, so I don't know if you'd need to do the same here.

But you should not embed the values like this. Use bind variables, as you already are for the return value. That will be more efficient as the query won't get a hard-parse for each set of values. More importantly it will help you to avoid SQL injection.